# not able to source bash_profile in mac

Tags: bash

I have added following lines to .bash_profile

```
export SASE_HOME = /Users/Amar/Downloads/sase-master
```

when I am trying to source, I am getting following error

```
Amar@dhcp-43-70:~$ source ~/.bash_profile
    -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
    -bash: export: `': not a valid identifier
    -bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
    -bash: export: `/Users/Amar/Downloads/sase-master': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: There must not be space around the `=` in variable assignments in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export SASE_HOME="/Users/Amar/Downloads/sase-master"
```

Comment: still getting error     source ~/.bash_profile
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `': not a valid identifier

Comment: I think I messed up with some other line in the bash_profile file ( because I am getting the same error even when in commented this line ). Is there a way, I can receive stack trace showing, line number on which there is an issue in bash_profile

Comment: @AmarjitSingh It sounds like you may have forgotten to close a quote on a previous line, or used a "smart" quote instead of a regular ASCII quote.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks a lot. The previous line included an export statement, which I have commented, for now as shown below.  it was not giving me any issues before, but after adding a line below it did. 

 #export ANDROID_NDK_HOME = ""
export SASE_HOME="/Users/Amar/Downloads/sase-master"

I appreciate everybody's help in this post, Have a great day!